# coldfusion + xml

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I can't believe how crap I am at XML.
I have the following xml structure derived from a larger xml document using xpath:

```
XmlName   HomeTeam
XmlNsPrefix  null   
XmlNsURI     null
XmlText   France
XmlComment   null   
XmlAttributes   
     alternateId  409
     id           21
```

The coldfusion code for narrowing the document down to this structure is:

```
<cfset homeTeam = XmlSearch(myXml,"/SportalData/Sport/LiveScores/Competition/Match/HomeTeam/") />
```

Now, all I want to do is access the XMLText value ("France") and use it in my html.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming the variable `homeTeam` is the result of an `xmlSearch()` call then `homeTeam` is an array so this should work:

```
<cfset team = homeTeam[1].xmlText />
```

Obviously, just be aware that the array length can be zero if the node is not found.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I edited this as my original answer was incorrect and failed to take into account the fact that `homeTeam` was the result of an `XMLSearch()` call.